# diagonalizing a submatrix of a matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

Suppose we are given a symmetric matrix $M$ of size $n\times n$ which I know to be diagonalized by the matrix $O$, i.e., $O^TMO$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $M$.

Suppose I consider a submatrix $M'$ of $M$ (say the first $n/2$ rows and first $n/2$ columns of $M$) and I know that $M'$ is diagonalizable. My goal is to diagonalize $M'$. Is there any way I can diagonalize $M'$ by $O$? Or is there any generic way that I can diagonalize a submatrix (M') of a matrix (M) (which is known to be diagonalized by a matrix $O$)

Comment: Your matrix doesn't look lika a matrix at all. What is $x\cdot y$? What is $|x|$?

Comment: does the edit help?

Comment: Not really. $M_{x,y}$ is a number, not a matrix.

Comment: Im specifying the entries of matrix $M$.

Comment: @Annonymous Perhaps you can write **explicitly** your matrix since as it is given it is, to say the least, very confusing. You could give 1-2 examples to make clear your intention.